# Bring wife from Germany to the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, germany, eu-spouses, uk-visa, uk-citizenship

I am asking on behalf of my brother.

My brother is a British national. He brought his wife from Afghanistan to Germany where he has been living and working for the last 4 months. Now, he is planning on coming to the UK.

1. Does he need to be working in the UK before he applies for a visa for his wife to enter the UK?
2. What document(s) does he need in applying for his wife's UK visa?
3. When his wife comes to the UK, when does she apply for Indefinite Leave to Remain or a British passport? In the future, will she need to pass the English language test?

Comment: Before he commits to moving immediately to the UK, he should read about [Surinder Singh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(Secretary_of_State_for_the_Home_Department)_v_Immigration_Appeal_Tribunal_and_Surinder_Singh).

Comment: Further to @PatriciaShanahan's comment, here's the UK government's link on the Surinder Singh route: https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/surinder-singh.  The advantage of this route is that it allows British citizens to take family members to the UK without financial requirements, language tests or exorbitant fees (currently thousands of pounds).

Comment: How long do you have to have lived in Germany before being able to make a Surinder Singh application?