# Settlement visa without taking the English test

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa

I have a serious matter for which I hope I can get help.

I have three children who are British by descent and have British passports.  My wife is an Afghan national who can't speak English which seems to make it impossible to bring her to the UK.

I have been told by a solicitor that I can bring her to the UK on a settlement visa without her taking the English test. The solicitor offers a no-win no-fee contract.

My question is whether there is any law or article or anything else that says that my wife can come to the UK without taking the English test, or is this guy wasting my time?

Comment: From your earlier questions, you are/were in Germany. Has that changed and you're in the UK?

Comment: Did you review the information and links provided by PatriciaShanahan and phoog in response to [your earlier question](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/9565/bring-wife-from-germany-to-the-uk) which explained how to accomplish this?

Comment: OP has not returned to answer questions, closing as unclear.